# php/jquery - check if image in url really exists

Tags: php, image, url

I found this nifty way to check if a page really exists:

```
$headers=@get_headers($imageurl);
if(strpos($headers[0],'200')===false){
    echo "not valid";
    exit;
}
```

What I need to achieve, though, is to check whether on that page is really only an image.
For example, when you try the following link:
www.google.com/image.jpg
it will return 200 because Google has it's own error page - however, it should be possible to find out not only that there is no image on that page, but also that an image is not the only thing on that page, even when there is other content (like here: http://www.kapstadt-entdecken.de/wp-content/gallery/robben-island/1robben-island.jpg).

How I can I achieve that?

Thanks a lot!

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use HEAD requests when getting headers (it doesn't do that by default):

```
stream_context_set_default(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'HEAD'
    )
));
```

Second, you can pass a second parameter to `get_headers` to parse it for you:

```
$headers = get_headers($imageurl, 1);
```

Then, you can check the rest as per normal:

```
if (strpos($headers[0], '200') === false) {
    echo "not valid";
    exit;
}

if (isset($headers['Content-Type']) && 0 === strncmp($headers['Content-Type'], 'image/', 6)) {
    echo "valid image";
} else {
    echo "probably not an image";
}
```

Comment: I only need to check if it doesn't work, so I changed it to: if (!isset($headers['Content-Type']) && 0 === strncmp($headers['Content-Type'], 'image/', 6)) {
    echo "not valid";
    exit;
} doesn't work unfortunately...

Comment: The inverse is `!isset($headers['Content-Type']) || 0 !== strncmp($headers['Content-Type'], 'image/', 6)`

Comment: no I was mistaken. it works like a charm. although the inverse only works like this apparently: if(!isset($headers['Content-Type']) && 0 === strncmp($headers['Content-Type'], 'image/', 6))

Comment: but I agree that it should actually be || 0 !=

Comment: You should `var_dump($headers);` to find out why this happens, because your inverted logic is wrong, that shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = @get_headers($imageurl);

$is_image = false;
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    if (strpos($header, 'Content-Type: image/') === 0) {
        $is_image = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also with get_headers ... one of them will be

```
image/png
image/jpeg
image/gif
```

so

```
$isImage = false;
foreach($headers as $header){
    if(strpos($header,'image/')==true){
        $isImage = true;
    }
}
```